# UITableViewCell add animation right after insert animation completes

Tags: ios, animation, uitableview, uikit

I have a table view which on the press of a button is populated with a new cell. The cell is added with Right animation(the cell comes in from the right). I would like to add another animation right after the insert animation completes (I would like the cell to move back to the right a bit and then back, macking it look like it bounced). My question is where do I add this animation, should I add it in cellForRowAtIndexPath or right after the call to insertRowsAtIndexPath so the animation runs right after the insert animation and how would I get the cell's view so i can animate it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't reload table. After writing code for `insertRowsAtIndexPath` just after `endUpdates` Write the bounce animation code here.
Get your tablecell like this .

```
  UITableViewCell *cell= [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Comment: So I tried this and it kinda works..The bounce animation does sho but now the insert animation does not run...I want to run my custom animation right after the insert animation.